# ASP.net Deployment

Tags: asp.net, configuration, iis-7, web-config

I am currently looking into devloping an ASP.NET website. I have configured IIS7 on my development machine as well as my server.

I have copied the development files to the local IIS server on my development machine and this works fine without any problems.

However, when I upload the ASP.NET application to my site via FTP in VS2010 to `mydomain.com/myasp` it displays an error which says:

> Description: An error occurred during
>   the processing of a configuration file
>   required to service this request.
>   Please review the specific error
>   details below and modify your
>   configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: It is an error
>   to use a section registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication'
>   beyond application level.  This error
>   can be caused by a virtual directory
>   not being configured as an application
>   in IIS.
>
> Source Error:  Line 34: ASP.NET to
>   identify an incoming user.  Line 35:
>   -->  Line 36: Line 37: section enables
>   configuration

I've converted the directory within IIS to an application but it is still coming up with the error.

Any help you can provide would be great thanks

Comment: Post a screenshot or the exact wording?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470136/configuring-an-asp-net-application-in-iis. You said you created an Application, did you set Execute Permissions to Scripts Only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out it was because I was calling the ASPX from http://localhost/myaspx.aspx directly on the server for some reason this causes the error. When I tried it http://www.mydomain.com/myaspx.aspx it worked fine.

Bit of a strange problem why it doesn't like using localhost. I'm guessing this must be a mis-configuration problem with iis

Comment: Is localhost defined in the hosts file?